# SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake failure

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, openssl, handshake

Here I block on a subject "pretty simple", and I can not have the support of the response solution provider.

I try to use the Payline libraries (payment provider) but it does not. Nothing I did was download their library, create a class that tests their example, but the script returns me the following exception:

for info, link to see the downloaded content Payline:https://support.payline.com/hc/fr/articles/201001237-Kit-d-int%C3%A9gration-JAVA

The exception :

```
Apr 30, 2015 9:56:06 AM com.experian.payline.ws.wrapper.DirectPayment doAuthorization
SEVERE: Error during doAuthorization call :
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:117)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:194)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:122)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:123)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:626)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:585)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:570)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:467)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:308)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:163)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:135)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.doAuthorization(Unknown Source)
at com.experian.payline.ws.wrapper.DirectPayment.doAuthorization(DirectPayment.java:110)
at test.launch.main(launch.java:42)

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.https.HttpsClien...ient.java:563)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.https.AbstractDe...tion.java:185)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.http.HttpURLConn...ion.java:1092)
at sun.net.http://www.protocol.https.HttpsURLCo...Impl.java:250)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:105)

... 15 more
```

and my code :

```
package test;

import java.util.Date;

import com.experian.payline.kit.utils.ConnectParams;
import com.experian.payline.ws.impl.DoAuthorizationResponse;
import com.experian.payline.ws.obj.Card;
import com.experian.payline.ws.obj.Order;
import com.experian.payline.ws.obj.Payment;
import com.experian.payline.ws.wrapper.DirectPayment;

public class launch {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        //System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
        ConnectParams params = new ConnectParams(null, false, true, "**************", "***************");

        DirectPayment directPayment = new DirectPayment(params);

        System.out.println(params.getProxyPort());

            Payment payment = new Payment();
            payment.setAmount("990"); 
            payment.setCurrency("978"); 
            payment.setAction("101"); 
            payment.setMode("CPT"); 
            payment.setContractNumber("0001/1234567"); 
            Order order = new Order();
            Date dNow = new Date();
            order.setRef("KIT_"+dNow.getTime());
        order.setAmount(payment.getAmount());
        order.setCurrency(payment.getCurrency());
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat s = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"); 
        order.setDate(s.format(dNow));
        Card card = new Card(); 
        card.setType("CB"); 
        card.setNumber("1111222233334444"); 
        card.setExpirationDate("0118"); 
        card.setCvx("123");
        DoAuthorizationResponse res = directPayment.doAuthorization(payment, order, null, card, null, null, null, null);

        System.out.println(res.getResult());

}

}
```

debug ssl

```
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal     alert: handshake_failure
main, called close()
```

I'm searching, I still can not correct this problem "handshake failure".

I tested this code on my Mac and on a Debian server (Java 7 on 2)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please post the exact URL you are using to connect to the server, and post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname> | openssl x509 -text -noout`. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment). Otherwise, there's not enough information to help troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0):

You mention in your question that you have used java 7.

The link you posted says compatible versions are Java 1.5 and Java 1.6.That the code is tested and working on these version.

Please check with java 1.6 . It could easily be a compatibility issue.

## From the link

https://support.payline.com/hc/fr/articles/201001237-Kit-d-int%C3%A9gration-JAVA

Compatibility Kit

## JAVA kit is tested in the following environments:

Windows XP Pro / Windows 7 Pro
Tomcat 5.5 and 6.0.35
Java 1.5 & 1.6

Comment: I have the error with java 1.6 : main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)